# Calling bool function inside if parameters

Tags: c++, if-statement, g++, boolean

so I have a C++ bool function that I've written that looks like this:

```
bool EligibileForDiscount(const char CompanyUsed, const char CompanySubscribed)
{

bool eligible = false;
    if (CompanyUsed==CompanySubscribed)
            eligible = true;

 return (eligible);

 }
```

Now in my main() this function is called as the only parameter for an if statement:

```
   if (EligibleForDiscount(CompanyUsed, CompanySubscribed))
       {
           ApplyDiscount(Cost, CompanySubscribed);
           cout << "\nAfter your discount, your rental is: $"
           << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << Cost << ".\n";
       }
```

The main function was written by my teacher and we wrote the other functions, so this if statement isn't supposed to be changed.

So I understand what the if statement is trying to accomplish, by basically saying "if (true) do this..." since the EligibleForDiscount will return a boolean value.

However, g++ is giving me an error with the if statement, telling me that EligibleForDiscount is not declared in this scope.

But I'm not trying to use it as a value but as a call to a function.

Comment: Is it declared in a header and you forgot to `#include` it?

Comment: I suspect the problem is a typo. You initially name the function `EligibileForDiscount()`, which is one letter off from what you call, `EligibleForDiscount()`.

Comment: Note that the whole mess of code in the function can be reduced to `return CompanyUsed==CompanySubscribed;`

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of two reasons:

You misspelled the function name when called : if (EligibleForDiscount(CompanyUsed, CompanySubscribed)) should be written like your implementation of the function, which is EligibileForDiscount.

This can happen if you forgot to declare the prototype of the function, which is an indicator to the program that you're going to use that function. You simply need to write somewhere before you use the function bool EligibileForDiscount(const char , const char)

One of these should work!

Comment: It would be better to change the function name to match the correct spelling, rather than to change the function call to match the incorrectly-spelled name.

Comment: Oh haha yeah it was just the misspelling of Eligible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because : EligibileForDiscount != EligibleForDiscount with an additional "i", just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

p.s. you can write `EligibleForDiscount` like this:

```
bool EligibleForDiscount(const char CompanyUsed, const char CompanySubscribed)
{
 return CompanyUsed==CompanySubscribed;
}
```